# Mathematical expression for randomly selecting from two integers

Tags: random, integers

I wonder what is the shortest and correct mathematical expression for the below:

$x =$ random$(1$ or $2)$ where there is equal probability of selecting 1 or 2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: uniformly  distributed on $\{1,2\}$

Comment: is it correct to say $x \sim$ U$\{1,2\}$?

Comment: hm... I haven't ever read that notation for the discrete uniform distribution. However, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: so what I am trying to say is $x \sim$ Uniform$\{1,2\}$. I know it can be used for when it is not discrete for example $x \sim$ U$(\[1,2\])$, hence I though it can also be used for discrete uniform distribution ?

Comment: if you explain it in text, it is surely okay. Notice that the English Wikipedia use the notation $\mathcal U\{a,b\}$ for the discrete uniform distribution on $\{a, a+1, \dotsc, b\}$. So seems to be known.